# How do I write O(n2) program of matrix n x n?

Tags: python, algorithm, matrix

I am practicing and trying to write O(n^2) program that tests whether there are two 1s lying on the same row or the same column in A.  Where A = n x n matrix of 0s and 1s.
Given A as:

[image: n x n matrix]

I should get answer return of 2 matches.
One is on the 1st row, and another on the 3rd column.

My 2nd Attempt:

```
def testLines():
    count = 0
    for x in range( 0, len(A)-1 ): 
        if( (A[x] == 1) & (A[x+1] == 1) ): 
        count+=1
    for y in range( 0, len(A)-1): 
        if( (A[y] == 1 & A[y+1]) == 1 ): 
        count+=1
    print( count, '1s has been matched in the array A')


testLines()
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. See [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). We cannot effectively help you until you post your MRE code and accurately specify the problem. We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you specified.
Your posted code is not properly indented; it fails to run, because `A` is undefined; you do not describe or demonstrate any problem.

Comment: @Prune Thanks, was looking for how to represent power of 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to nest the two loops and change the indexes so that both x and y are parsed. Currently your code moves through (all x, y = 0) and (x = 0, all y).

```
A = [[0, 0, 1, 1],
     [0, 1, 0, 0],
     [0, 0, 1, 0],
     [0, 0, 1, 0]]

def testLines():
    count = 0
    N = len(A)
    for x in range(N): 
        for y in range(N):
            if A[x][y] == 1:
                if x+1 < N and A[x+1][y] == 1: 
                    count += 1
                if y+1 < N and A[x][y+1] == 1: 
                    count += 1
    print(count, '1s has been matched in the array A')

testLines()
```

Alternatively, you can go the Schwarzenegger way and not check if `(x+1, y)` or `(x, y+1)` even exist. That will raise `IndexError`s that you can choose to ignore.

```
def testLines():
    count = 0
    N = len(A)
    for x in range(N): 
        for y in range(N):
            try:
                if A[x][y] == 1 and A[x+1][y] == 1 or A[x][y+1] == 1: 
                    count += 1
            except IndexError:
                continue
    print(count, '1s has been matched in the array A')
```

Comment: You need the tests for x+1 < N and y+1 < N before checking if A[x+1][y]==1 and A[x][y+1]==1 in the and conditionals.  Otherwise you will get an index out of range error.

Comment: @Guimoute I don't quite understand the end of the 6th line:         x +1 < N:

Comment: @MrCEO You need to make sure `A[x+1][y]` actually exists. You did it in your original post by reducing the `range`, I do it by adding a `if` condition. A third option would be to not check at all and ignore any `IndexError` that would be raised because of that line.

Comment: @Guimoute  I am getting this message:    TypeError: 'int' does not support indexing.     This line  ----    if A[x][y] == 1:

Comment: @MrCEO Then that means you are using a 1D list/array... I added an example of `A` to the answer and with this format it works.

Answer (score 0):

You can run one nested loop (n²) to get summation of rows. If summation is 2 then that row has two 1s.

Now interchange rows and columns(consider rows as columns & vice versa).

Again run nested loop (n²) to check summation of columns.

n²+n²= O(n²)